# Warrning in PHP email "It contains content that's typically used to steal personal information"

Tags: php, email

**After I use the email script, in email the following warning appears:**

> Be careful with this message. It contains content that's typically
>   used to steal personal information. Learn more Report this suspicious
>   message   Ignore, I trust this message

```
$email_subject =  $cnm ." |$cnm.com";
        $email_message ="<HTML><BODY><TABLE>";
        $email_message .= "<TR><TD> Job Descrption :".$jb_des ."</TD></TR>";
        $email_message .="<TR><TD>Employer Name :".$frm_nm." </TD></TR>" ;
        $email_message .="<TR><TD>Company Name :".$cnm." </TD></TR>";
        $email_message .="<TR><TD>Message :".$msg." </TD></TR>";
        $email_message .="<TR><TD>Title of Job Opening :".$job_ti." </TD></TR>" ;
        $email_message .="</TABLE></BODY></HTML>";
        $headers = "From:<$frm_nm@abc.com>". "\r\n";
        $headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 ". "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        @mail($to_em,$email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: Please give us more information. Show us your script.

Comment: Ok, i have used the php email script ,After the email is delivered in email a red alert box appearing with the msg  i have mentioned above ,if yo wish i can post email code

Comment: Do you really own `abc.com` If you forge your sender address, then you're doing **Email Spoofing** always trigger mail from the exact senders that you have. Never ever change the sender address in the headers while triggering the email.

Comment: no , i have domain name which i have replaced in upper code

Comment: The message can be produced by your email client, the antivirus software you have installed on the workstation where you read the email, some anti-spam software installed on the server where the email is stored or by the mailing system itself (it is it one of the big webmail hosters). It looks like you are reading the email using GMail and your message looks like spam to it (because it analyzed in the past a lot of emails that look similar to yours and were marked as spam by the users that received them). Read this: http://goo.gl/k1bxfa

Answer (score 0):

This warning is appearing because the email host of the address you're sending the email to cannot verify that you're the real sender of the email. Their email server knows that the information you're sending is questionable.

Unless the email is really coming from the domain: "abc.com" for example it's likely that this warning will appear for whoever is viewing the email.

This could also be caused by information or links in the email which the receiver's email server doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

Either your message contains a scam web page that steal users informations or the Domain/IP of your server has been used in the past for stealing personal informations.

Check IP if is blacklisted on [Mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)
Configure Reverse DNS (Match your domain name with your IP), SPF and DKIM, Send legitimate email and everything will be fine