# Emails landing with red banner in gmail inbox

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

Suddenly all the emails sent through gmail api are landing with a red banner in recipients inbox as shown below.

[image: Sent using gmail api]

So, I created a new OAuth ClientID in Google Cloud platform and used those credentials to provide access to my test gmail account. Then I sent emails using Gmail Api and emails are landing in inbox without any red banner which is good.

But we need to use the same old OAuth ClientID as we have so many users who provided access to it. If we change these ClientID and ClientSecret to use the new one, we need all our users to re-authorize, which we don't want to do. Can someone help why the existing OAuth Client ID is throwing this red banner in recipients mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [blog](https://www.digitbin.com/gmail-warning-message-steal-personal-information/), this warning message speaks about one of the security measures taken by Google. Also from this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403120/warrning-in-php-email-it-contains-content-thats-typically-used-to-steal-person), either your message contains a scam web page that steal users informations or the Domain/IP of your server has been used in the past for stealing personal informations. *Check if IP is blacklisted on [Mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) Configure Reverse DNS (Match your domain name with your IP), SPF and DKIM, Send legitimate email and everything will be fine*.